# why ng-transclude not working in angular js as expected

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I make a simple directed with isolated scope .I read the tutorial of transclude but when I apply it not working as expected .I need to show "dd" and test together how I can show this 
here is my plunker
http://plnkr.co/edit/OxmVga7DdkNxzPnfDtGS?p=preview

```
 var app =angular.module('app',[]);
  app.directive('newdir',function(){
    return {
      restrict:"E",
      scope:{
        fr:'@'
      },
      replace:true,
    transclude: true, // we want to insert custom content inside the directive
      template:"<div ng-transclude >{{fr}}</div>"

    }
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The transcluded element gets completely replaced.  Replace your template with this to see what is happening:

```
<div><h3>BEFORE</h3><h1 ng-transclude>MISSING</h1><h3>AFTER</h3>{{fr}}</div>
```

Comment: why it is replaced ? ng-transclude used when text of directive and template of directive together

Comment: `ng-transclude` tells angular what to replace in the template with what is in the original directive element.  It is completely replaced so you know exactly where the content is being transcluded.  If completely replaced not then in my example you wouldn't know if the original `dd` was supposed to go before or after `MISSING`.